# How to set a reminder in windows calendar

Tags: python, windows

I was looking for a module to work with a standard windows calendar but didn't find anything useful, I just want a script that can access the default calendar and set a reminder. Can you suggest a proper module to perform these actions?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `win32com.client` module, heres's an example:

```
import win32com.client
import datetime

# Create an instance of the Windows Calendar COM object
calendar = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")

# Set the reminder details
subject = "MyReminder"
body = "Characteristics of MyReminder"
start = datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 7, 14, 0) 
duration = 60 # in minutes

# Create a new appointment item in the calendar
appointment = calendar.CreateItem(1) # 1 = Appointment

# Set the appointment details
appointment.Subject = subject
appointment.Body = body
appointment.Start = start
appointment.Duration = duration
appointment.ReminderSet = True
appointment.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15 # reminder will appear 15 minutes before the start time

# Save the appointment to the calendar
appointment.Save()
```